# VBA Excel InStr(myString) returns no result

Tags: excel, vba

I want to multiply my range of cells by -1 when they matches the Instr criteria.

[image]

but I still get positive values, which are based on my `else` statement.

Basically, I use the ConverdDecimal function from this link:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1497-excel-convert-decimal-degrees-to-degrees-minutes-seconds.html

with doesn't cope well with negative values. Hence I have to modify my code.

```
   Sub Sun()
   Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rngB As Range, rngC As Range
   Dim wors As Worksheet
   Dim myString As String

   Set wors = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

   Dim lastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long

   wors.Columns("E").Copy
   wors.Columns("P").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   wors.Columns("F").Copy
   wors.Columns("R").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

   lastRow = wors.Range("P" & wors.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   LastRow2 = wors.Range("Q" & wors.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng = wors.Range("P1:P" & lastRow)
   Set rngB = wors.Range("R1:R" & lastRow)
   Set rngC = wors.Range("F1:F" & lastRow)

   For Each cell In rng
   cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, " ", "° ", 1)
   cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, " ", "' ", 2)
   Next

   For Each cell In rngB
   cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "-", "")
   cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, " ", "° ", 1)
   cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, " ", "' ", 2)
   Next


  With words
  Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Formula = "=ConvertDecimal(P2)"
  Columns("Q").Copy
  Columns("X").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Range("S2:S" & lastRow).Formula = "=ConvertDecimal(R2)"
  End With

  With rngC
  If InStr(myString, "-") <> 0 Then
  Range("T2:T" & lastRow).Formula = "=S2 * -1 "
  Else
  Range("T2:T" & lastRow).Formula = "=S2"
  End If
  End With
  End Sub
```

I tried:

```
   Range("T2:T" & lastRow).Formula = "=S2 * (-1) "
   Range("T2:T" & lastRow).Formula = "=-S2"
   Range("T2:T" & lastRow).Formula = "=-1 * S2"
```

Nothing works

What is wrong with my code? Why does it cove only the `Else` situation? I need negative formulas wherever the "-" appears in column F.

Comment: Where is `myString` assigned?

Comment: I have Dim myString As String

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete code

Comment: @RicardoDiaz see my full code

Comment: after `Dim myString As String` the value of `myString` is an empty string. You didn't show how you put a value in this variable. Check the value using `Debug.Print myString` it is empty, therefore you cannot find a `"-"` in it.

Comment: is it failing because of this typo and you do not have option explcit? `With words` - `words` is not defined but `wors` is

Comment: I have Option Explicit at the top

Comment: @MKR you can't have `Option Explicit` this code would throw an error at `With words` also that `With` block is useless. It is never used, because no line in it starts with a dot. As your other with blocks which are not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why this would not work: For cell `T2` use the formula

```
=IF(LEFT(TRIM(F2), 1)="-", -1, 1)*S2
```

or if you want to do it in VBA

```
Range("T2:T" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1="=IF(LEFT(TRIM(RC6), 1)=""-"", -1, 1)*RC[-1]"
```

Comment: No, is something with the InSrt

If InStr(myString, "-") > 0 Then
your code 
Else
Range("T2:T" & lastRow).Formula = "=S2"
End If

returns only S2

Comment: I'm sorry @MKR I dont understand that, could you re-phrase? Maybe give an explicit example of where this doesnt work to illustrate why and so add a bit of clarity to the requirement? thanks

Comment: @MKR Because you did not put any value in `myString`. It is empty. `myString` is `""` nothing in there. You need to put a value before you can use it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you were right. After adding  myString = "-"   everything works perfect. Thank you

Comment: @MKR If you set `myString = "-"` that does not make any sense at all because then `InStr(myString, "-")` is the same as `InStr("-", "-")` which is **always** `<> 0`. This is definitely wrong. `myString` has to be set to the cell value you want to check for a `"-"`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ OK thank you, I will remember it. So I should pick up the cell with the string, where the "-" occur, shouldn't I?

Comment: @MKR yes `myString` needs to be the cell that you want to check for a `"-"`.

Answer (score 0):

is it failing because of this typo and you do not have `option explicit`?

```
With words
```

`words` is not defined but `wors` is so if no `option explcit` a variable `words` is created at runtime but is set to nothing so nothing happens inside the `with` block

Comment: No the `With words` block is never used. No line starts with a dot in it. The `With` block is useless.